# Cross-Platform Python Notification Library

Tags: python, cross-platform, notifications

I'm making a python script that should run in the background and notify a user of changes, and I'd quite like it to work cross-platform. Main problem is, I don't have access to a mac at all, so coding specifically for it could be very difficult. wxPython seems like massive overkill for simple popups, so is there anything with a lighter footprint?

Comment: on Linux, isn't OSD notify good enough? it's already available on Ubuntu/Fedora by default.

Comment: Yeah, OSD notify is perfect. If I have to, I'll just use that on linux, Snarl on windows, and Growl on mac, but I figure it'd be nice to have something if people don't want to install/don't use those.

Comment: Since the OS's a *different* what would "cross platform" mean?  Can you give examples of any existing packages which meet your definition of "cross platform"?

Comment: Python itself! Run the same script on any OS with a minimum of changing, if any at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does Python on Windows and Mac also ship with Tk wrappers? If so, you might be able to roll your own notification box. I do not think they have a dead-simple notification API (i.e. you pass it a string and a cute box pops up for 5 seconds) however at least you will only have one codebase to maintain.

I am thinking about other cross-platform apps such as Skype, Dropbox, and Thunderbird. Skype and Thunderbird seem to have rolled their own, and Dropbox went the platform-specific route.

Comment: I just tried `import Tkinter`, and nothing went wrong, so I think this should do great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Wave](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wave/) is a cross-platform notification framework however I have not used it and I do not believe it is a desktop-oriented deal, but rather something for rich Internet Apps and plugging into web sites. Still, it's some sort of cross-platform notification so possibly worth a look-see.

That reminds me, you may be able to find an AIR notification system out there that you could somehow trigger from Python. Mono with GTK# comes to mind as it supports the three major desktop platforms. See this [GtkSharpNotification](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpNotificationIcon) example perhaps.

Finally, for my third strike, maybe a cross-platform GUI toolkit like wxWidgets has the widget you need.

Comment: All good suggestions! Unfortunately, it all really seems like overkill for literally just a box that pops onto and off the screen! :(

Comment: Yes it definitely depends on your situation and whether it's a retail app, business app, or what. I admit, I find none of my ideas very compelling but you're trying to avoid mainaining three codebases, long-term.

Comment: They're good ideas, and I'd certainly consider them if this were a larger project, but it's not at all :(

Comment: Just added a second shoot-from-the-hip answer about Tk. Sorry, I'm all out of ideas! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one way to go would be something like Growl/GNTP. Have you looked at [python's gntp library](https://github.com/kfdm/gntp/)?